# Interaction of attr_accessor and |= operator

Tags: ruby

I understand that `x |= y` basically means `x = x|y`. The operator `|` is defined for the class `Set` as calculating the union of two sets. Indeed we can see:

```
require 'set'
r = Set.new(%w(a b)); 
s = Set.new(%w(c d)); 
r |= s; # r => #<Set: {"a", "b", "c", "d"}>
```

But see for instance the following class definition:

```
class Demo; 
  def initialize(s); 
    @x = s.dup; 
  end; 
  attr_accessor :x; 
  def m!(t); 
    x |= t.x; ' <--- HERE TROUBLE!
 end;
```

end

I'm using this class like this:

```
u = Demo.new(Set.new(%w(a b)))
v = Demo.new(Set.new(%w(c d)))
u.m!(v)
```

If I now look at u.x, I see that it still holds the set *a,b* and not *a,b,c,d*. My feeling is that this comes from the fact I'm using the attribut accessor, in particular the setter method. If I would write `@x |= t.x`, it would work. Could it be that the left hand side of `x |= t.x` uses the *getter* `x` and not the *setter* `x=`, thereby creating the union in a temporary Set object?

BTW, I'm using a fairly old version of Ruby (JRuby 1.7.x, corresponding roughly to the language version of Ruby 1.9.3).

Comment: Alternatively: `x.merge(t.x)` which adds the elements from `t.x` to `x`. (without creating a new set)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that in

```
x = 3
```

`x` is always interpreted as a local variable before ruby starts looking for a method `x=`. This means, that your method translates to:

```
def m!(t)
  x = nil # local variable initialization
  x = x | t.x
end;
```

To solve this, you need to use explicit `self` to force method call:

```
def m!(t); 
  self.x |= t.x
end
```

Another note - please do not use semicolons in ruby. There are only a very rare situations they needed but we generally avoid them

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods): _"When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you do not have a receiver, Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local variable"_